# tkinter gui layout using frames and grid

Tags: python, layout, tkinter, frame

My [gui layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VHvr.jpg)

[image: gui layout]

looks almost nothing like [what I expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYPtK.jpg)

[image: what I expect]

so I assume there are some basics that I don't understand.

I assumed that frames contain their own 'grid space' (row, column) but the behavior I see doesn't bear that out, and I'm at a loss for getting things working the way I want for the top frame.  My labels are supposed to be on the same row L to R, under a 'frame label' that spans the entire frame - except they don't. I want the actual to look more like the goal jpg, and I want to use grid to do it.

You can just see one of the entry fields to the right of the green frame.  Why is it going there ?

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Model Definition')
root.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(460, 350))

top_frame = Frame(root, bg='cyan', width = 450, height=50, pady=3).grid(row=0, columnspan=3)
Label(top_frame, text = 'Model Dimensions').grid(row = 0, columnspan = 3)
Label(top_frame, text = 'Width:').grid(row = 1, column = 0)
Label(top_frame, text = 'Length:').grid(row = 1, column = 2)
entry_W = Entry(top_frame).grid(row = 1, column = 1)
entry_L = Entry(top_frame).grid(row = 1, column = 3)
#Label(top_frame, text = '').grid(row = 2, column = 2)

center = Frame(root, bg='gray2', width=50, height=40, padx=3, pady=3).grid(row=1, columnspan=3)
ctr_left = Frame(center, bg='blue', width=100, height=190).grid(column = 0, row = 1, rowspan = 2)
ctr_mid = Frame(center, bg='yellow', width=250, height=190, padx=3, pady=3).grid(column = 1, row=1, rowspan=2)
ctr_right = Frame(center, bg='green', width=100, height=190, padx=3, pady=3).grid(column = 2, row=1, rowspan=2)

btm_frame = Frame(root, bg='white', width = 450, height = 45, pady=3).grid(row = 3, columnspan = 3)
btm_frame2 = Frame(root, bg='lavender', width = 450, height = 60, pady=3).grid(row = 4, columnspan = 3)


root.mainloop()
```

So specifically, where did my labels and Entry widgets go, and how do I get them to look more like the goal (top frame, the rest are for later).

Comment: if would help slightly if the two images uses the same color scheme, unless they are and you're saying that the blue window really should be on the bottom even though the code puts it on the left.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

> I assumed that frames contain their own 'grid space'

That is a correct assumption.

> You can just see one of the entry fields to the right of the green
>   frame. Why is it going there ?

The problem starts here:

```
top_frame = Frame(root, ...).grid(row=0, ...)
```

In python, `x = y().z()` will always set `x` to the result of `.z()`. In the case of `top_frame = Frame(...).grid(...)`, `grid(...)` always returns `None` so `top_frame` will be `None`. That causes every widget that you think is going into the top frame to actually go in the root window.

## Solution Overview

As a general rule of thumb, you should never call `grid`, `pack` or `place` as part of the same statement that creates the widget. Partially it is for this exact behavior that you're experiencing, but also because I think it makes your code harder to write and harder to maintain over time.

Widget creation and widget layout are two different things. In my experience, layout problems are considerably easier to debug when you group your layout commands together.

Also, you should be consistent when using `grid` and always put the options in the same order so you can more easily visualize the layout. And finally, when using `grid` you should get in the habit of always specifying the `sticky` option, and always give one row and one column in each containing frame a non-zero weight.

## Solution Example

Here's how I would write your code. It's much longer, but much easier to understand.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Model Definition')
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(460, 350))

# create all of the main containers
top_frame = Frame(root, bg='cyan', width=450, height=50, pady=3)
center = Frame(root, bg='gray2', width=50, height=40, padx=3, pady=3)
btm_frame = Frame(root, bg='white', width=450, height=45, pady=3)
btm_frame2 = Frame(root, bg='lavender', width=450, height=60, pady=3)

# layout all of the main containers
root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

top_frame.grid(row=0, sticky="ew")
center.grid(row=1, sticky="nsew")
btm_frame.grid(row=3, sticky="ew")
btm_frame2.grid(row=4, sticky="ew")

# create the widgets for the top frame
model_label = Label(top_frame, text='Model Dimensions')
width_label = Label(top_frame, text='Width:')
length_label = Label(top_frame, text='Length:')
entry_W = Entry(top_frame, background="pink")
entry_L = Entry(top_frame, background="orange")

# layout the widgets in the top frame
model_label.grid(row=0, columnspan=3)
width_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
length_label.grid(row=1, column=2)
entry_W.grid(row=1, column=1)
entry_L.grid(row=1, column=3)

# create the center widgets
center.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
center.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

ctr_left = Frame(center, bg='blue', width=100, height=190)
ctr_mid = Frame(center, bg='yellow', width=250, height=190, padx=3, pady=3)
ctr_right = Frame(center, bg='green', width=100, height=190, padx=3, pady=3)

ctr_left.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ns")
ctr_mid.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
ctr_right.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="ns")

root.mainloop()
```

## Result:

[image: screenshot of running example]

Comment: wahoo - many, many thanks.  I will review carefully.  I concur with the color scheme comment, I didn't pay close enough attention.

Comment: I find that with either Python 2.7 or 3.5 commenting out all four mysterious commands of the `rowconfigure` and  `columnconfigure`  type in your script has no effect on the result (on the appearance of the window and its frame limits).

Comment: @MikeO'Connor: you will notice the difference as soon as you manually resize the window. Without the `rowconfigure` and `columnconfigure` commands the window will not resize properly.

Comment: Ah hah! Thanks for writing back. I was befuddled by the fact that the center frame has an initial assigned height of 40, yet the display with the `rowconfigure` and `columnconfigure` off somehow yields a center frame of much greater height... whereas the top and bottom frames seem to have their assigned heights. But now I see that it's the assigned ctr frame heights that effectively set the center frame initial height.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley: Great answer and a good template for tkinter projects!

Answer (score 7):

`variable = Widget(...).grid()` assigns `None` to variable because `grid()`/`pack()`/`place()` return `None`

use

```
variable = Widget(...)
variable.grid() # .pack() .place()
```