# tkinter gui fine tune widget layout

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, widget

This is a follow-on to an answered post - I assume it's poor form to add to an answered thread even if it's related.

Overall I'm pretty happy with the layout (heavy lifting done by Bryan O. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276663/tkinter-gui-layout-using-frames-and-grid)).

Now I'm trying to fine-tune some widgets, and I can't seem to nudge things.  In order to shift widgets I seem to need to layer additional frames to do so.  This seems like using a shotgun to kill a fly, but what do I know?

I would like to nudge the button 'Add Edges" over so it has some space between it and the number entry widget to the left.

I would also love to have some space between the ok and cancel buttons on the bottom.  Have tried adding padding via padx, and implementing layered frames whacks things up [bad layout truncated central region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nd7b3.jpg) pretty badly.I guess that geometry propagation means using padx isn't the right approach.

I cannot seem to nudge the widgets where I want them.  My question specifically: using the code base I have, how do you recommend I make these fine-tune adjustments??

Thx

[current gui layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/og9wD.jpg)

code:

```
 from Tkinter import *

root2 = Tk()
root2.title('Model Definition')
root2.geometry('{}x{}'.format(460, 350))

# functions/commands

def get_list(event):
    global seltext

    """
    read the listbox selection and put the result somewhere
    """

    # get selected line index
    index = data_list.curselection()[0]

    # get the line's text
    seltext = data_list.get(index)

    root2.update_idletasks()

# create all of the main containers
top_frame = Frame(root2, bg='cyan', width = 450, height=50, pady=6)
center = Frame(root2, bg='gray2', width=50, height=40, padx=3, pady=3)
btm_frame = Frame(root2, bg='plum4', width = 450, height = 45, pady=3)

btm_frame2_outer = Frame(root2, bg='lavender', width = 450, height = 60, pady=3)
btm_frame2 = Frame(btm_frame2_outer, bg='green', width = 350, height = 60, pady=3)
btm_frame2_cntr = Frame(btm_frame2_outer, bg='gray', width = 50, padx=7)

# layout all of the main containers
root2.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
root2.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

top_frame.grid(row=0, sticky="ew")
center.grid(row=1, sticky="nsew")
btm_frame.grid(row = 3, sticky="ew")

btm_frame2_outer.grid(row = 4, sticky="ew")
btm_frame2.grid(row = 1, columnspan = 2, sticky="ew")
btm_frame2_cntr.grid(row = 1, column = 4, sticky='ew')

# create the widgets for the top frame
model_label = Label(top_frame, text = 'Model Dimensions')
width_label = Label(top_frame, text = 'Width:')
length_label = Label(top_frame, text = 'Length:')
entry_W = Entry(top_frame, background="pink")
entry_L = Entry(top_frame, background="orange")

# layout the widgets in the top frame
model_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, pady=5)
width_label.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = 'e')
length_label.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
entry_W.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
entry_L.grid(row = 1, column = 3)

# create the center widgets
center.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
center.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

ctr_left = Frame(center, bg='blue', width=100, height=190)
ctr_mid = Frame(center, bg='yellow', width=250, height=190, padx=3, pady=3)
ctr_right = Frame(center, width=100, height=190, padx=3, pady=3)

ctr_left.grid(row=0, column = 0, sticky="ns")
ctr_mid.grid(row=0, column = 1, sticky="nsew")
ctr_right.grid(row=0, column = 2, sticky="ns")

# decorate the center frame widgets
# left
shift_up_label = Label(ctr_left, text = 'Shift Up')
shift_down_label = Label(ctr_left, text = 'Shift Down')
cut_label = Label(ctr_left, text = 'Cut')
copy_label = Label(ctr_left, text = 'Copy')
paste_label = Label(ctr_left, text = 'Paste')
# center
data_list = Listbox(ctr_mid, bg='snow2', width='55')
yscroll = Scrollbar(ctr_mid, command=data_list.yview, orient=VERTICAL)
# right
status_label = Label(ctr_right, text = 'Status', bg = 'green', height = 11)

#####################################################################
# layout the center widgets
#####################################################################
#left
shift_up_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, pady = '7', sticky = 'nsew')
shift_down_label.grid(row = 1, column = 0, pady = '7', sticky = 'nsew')
cut_label.grid(row = 2, column = 0, pady = '7', sticky = 'nsew')
copy_label.grid(row = 3, column = 0, pady = '7', sticky = 'nsew')
paste_label.grid(row = 4, column = 0, pady = '7', sticky = 'nsew')

# center
data_list.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ns')
yscroll.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ens')

# right
status_label.grid(row = 2, column = 0, rowspan = 4, sticky = 'nsew')
# create the bottom widgets
# layout the bottom widgets

#####################################################################
# create bottom widgets
#####################################################################
label_label = Label(btm_frame, text = 'Label:', padx = '4')
entry_label = Entry(btm_frame, background="orange")
entry_number = Entry(btm_frame, background="cyan")
number_label = Label(btm_frame, text = 'Number:', padx = '4')
add_btn = Button(btm_frame, text='Add Edges', padx = '12')
ok_btn = Button(btm_frame2_cntr, text='OK', padx = '5')
cancel_btn = Button(btm_frame2_cntr, text='Cancel', padx = '12')

#####################################################################
# layout the bottom widgets
#####################################################################
label_label.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = 'ew')
entry_label.grid(row = 1, column = 2, sticky = 'w')
number_label.grid(row = 1, column = 3, sticky = 'w')
entry_number.grid(row = 1, column = 4, sticky = 'e')
add_btn.grid(row = 1, column = 6, sticky = 'e')
ok_btn.grid(row = 0, column = 3, sticky = 'ew')
cancel_btn.grid(row = 0, column = 4, sticky = 'e')

# commands/bindings
data_list.configure(yscrollcommand=yscroll.set)
data_list.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', get_list)

root2.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to nudge the button 'Add Edges" over so it has some space
>   between it and the number entry widget to the left.

When you call `grid` on a widget, there are two options that control spacing on either side of the widget: `padx` and `pady`. You can specify a single value that applies to both sides (eg: `padx=20` will add 20 pixels on both the left and right side of the widget), or you can provide a two-tuple (eg: `padx=(0,20)` will only add 20 pixels on the right).

For example, to "nudge" the "Add Edges" button over, just add some padding:

```
add_btn.grid(row = 1, column = 6, sticky = 'e', padx=(20, 0))
```

> I would also love to have some space between the ok and cancel buttons
>   on the bottom.

Again, `padx` is the solution:

```
ok_btn.grid(row = 0, column = 3, sticky = 'ew', padx=(0, 8))
```

Comment: Yes!  It never occurred to me to feed padx/y a tuple, thanks so much!