# Nesting grids and frames in tkinter and python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to set up a grid inside of a frame which is in a larger grid structure.  I've tried to distill it to the simplest version of the problem.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Label, Entry

root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x800')


frame1 = Frame(root, width=400, height=400, background="Blue")
frame2 = Frame(root, width=400, height=400, background="Red")

frame1.grid(row=0, column=0)
frame2.grid(row=1, column=1)

label1 = Label(frame1,text='Label1')
label1.grid()
```

Instead of placing the label inside of frame1, the label replaces the frame in the overall grid:

[image: Sample output]

I've looked at other examples, but I haven't been able to identify why they work and mine does not.

Answer (score 3):

Using jasonharper's observation that the Frame was automatically resizing itself and a similar question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276663/tkinter-gui-layout-using-frames-and-grid), I was able to update the code.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Label

root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x800')

root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

frame1 = Frame(root, background="Blue")
frame2 = Frame(root, background="Red")

frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
frame2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")


label1 = Label(frame1,text='Label1')
label1.grid()
```

The changes that I made to the code are:

- I removed the height and width parameters from the Frame instances because they weren't doing anything anyway.
- Added weighting to the rows and columns of root, the container for the frames, to equally space the frames in the available space
- Add the 'sticky' parameter to the grid placements of the frames so that the frames would take up all of the space that they were allotted.

The result:

[image: New result]

Answer (score 2):

The `width=` and `height=` of a Frame normally only apply when it has no children.  Once child widgets are added, it resizes itself to fit its contents.  So `frame1` is still there, it's just now exactly the same size as, and entirely covered by, the label.

To turn off this auto-resizing behavior, call `.grid_propagate(0)` on the Frame (or `.pack_propagate(0)`, depending on the geometry manager being used for the Frame's children).

Comment: Though, turning off geometry propagation is almost never the right solution. Using it usually means you have to do a lot more work as a programmer to create a program that is responsive, and works well at different resolutions and with different fonts.

Comment: What is your approach then Brian?