# What would be the best way to position my GUI components

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm relatively new to coding in general and I'm wondering if there is a better way to position my GUI components. I'm using rows and columns, but it can be awkward as I have to use `padx` and `pady` to make my GUI look nice, is there an easier method of positioning these?

Example Code:

```
PageLabel=Label(Login,
            text="Login",
            font=('Arial Black',40),
            fg='white,
            bg='lightblue').grid(row=1,column=1,columnspan=4,padx=100)
```

Comment: try using  `Grid geometry manager`

Comment: Choose on of the [Geometry Manager Grid, Pack, or Place - Geometry mixins](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-classes.htm) read [gui layout using frames and grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276663/tkinter-gui-layout-using-frames-and-grid/34277295#34277295)

Comment: @prashantrana: they _are_ using the grid geometry manager.

Comment: We can't answer a "best way" question without knowing what you're specifically trying to achieve. `grid` is the best way when you are laying things out in a grid. `pack` is the best way when laying out widgets side-to-side or top-to-bottom, `place` is best for absolute positioning, and some combination in conjunction with frames for organization is best for an application overall. All of the approaches have both strengths and weaknesses.