# How do i use grid system so that a text box does not change column size

Tags: python, tkinter

[What i mean.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QP2wt.jpg)
(The Image above explains my problem)

My code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import os
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.ttk import *

window = tkinter.Tk()

text = Text(window)

def save():
    print("Save")

def load():
    print("Load")
def printcom():
    print("Print")


savebut = ttk.Button(window, text = "Save", command = save)
loadbut = ttk.Button(window, text = "Load", command = load)
printbut = ttk.Button(window, text = "Print", command = printcom)



savebut.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=1)
loadbut.grid(row=0,column=1, columnspan=1)
printbut.grid(row=0,column=2, columnspan=1)
text.grid(row=1,column=3, columnspan = 3)
```

I don't know how to get the text box to not change the column size

Comment: Do you mean `text.grid(row=1,column=0, columnspan = 3)`?

Comment: Aggregate your three `Button`'s in a own `Frame`. Read [gui layout using frames and grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276663/tkinter-gui-layout-using-frames-and-grid/34277295#34277295).