# Python GUI placing 3 frames in order - left right bottom

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Trying to place the bottom frame but it seems to get squeezed in between the left and right and not going bottom.. I'm trying to have left right bottom
frames that would be all bind to the window size (expandable / fill both)

tried different settings on fill x / y / expandables etc'
as well as making width height for the frames

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class Bank(object):
    def __init__(self, name, accounts=None):
        self.accounts = set(accounts)
        self.name = name


class Bank_Gui(object):
    def __init__(self, master, bank):
        self.master = master
        self.bank = bank

        self.master.title("Bank")
        self.master.geometry("800x600")

        self.left = Frame(self.master, borderwidth=5, relief="groove", highlightthickness=15)
        self.right = ttk.LabelFrame(self.master, borderwidth=5, relief="groove", text=" Details ")
        self.bottom = ttk.LabelFrame(self.master, borderwidth=5, relief="groove", text=" Transaction ")
        self.container = ttk.LabelFrame(self.left, borderwidth=5, relief="groove", text=" Customers ")

        self.left.pack(side="left", expand=True, fill="both")
        self.right.pack(side="right", expand=True, fill="both", padx=10, pady=10)
        self.bottom.pack(side="bottom", expand=True, fill="both", padx=10, pady=10)
        self.container.pack(expand=True, fill="both", padx=10, pady=10)


root = Tk()

bank_c = Bank("MyBank", [])

bg = Bank_Gui(root, bank_c)

root.mainloop()
```

Looking for a result quite similar in terms of frames :
http://wildcat.ow2.org/images/bank-gui.png

just missing the bottom frame.. kinda

Comment: Read [gui layout using frames and grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276663/tkinter-gui-layout-using-frames-and-grid/34277295#34277295)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to workaround it myself just made another frame "center" and put right and left frames into it, and then with two frames only "center" and "bottom" put them one above other worked. (TOP , TOP)