# how to change the position of dropdown using tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

im trying to make a simple dropdown gui,but i need some help on how to position the dropdown menu , the full code is :

```
import tkinter as tk

from tkinter import *

root=tk.Tk()




canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 400, height = 300)
canvas1.pack()

username = tk.Entry(root)
canvas1.create_window(200,140, window=username)
canvas1.create_text(100,140,fill="darkblue",text="username")

password = tk.Entry(root)
canvas1.create_window(200,180,window=password)
canvas1.create_text(100,180,fill="darkblue",text="password")

variable = StringVar(root)
variable.set("Facebook")

w=OptionMenu(root , variable, "Facebook","Twitter","Spotify","Swiggy")
w.pack()

button1= tk.Button(text='Go')
canvas1.create_window(250,250, window=button1)

root.mainloop()
```

the dropdown menu was obtained by using the OptionMenu but im unable to change its position, i need help with that
code for just the OptionMenu:

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()

variable = StringVar(master)
variable.set("one") # default value

w = OptionMenu(master, variable, "one", "two", "three")
w.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Why are you unable to change it's position? Where do you want it? It looks like you're succesfully calling `pack`, have you tried the various options to `pack`, or explored using `grid`?

Comment: Read [gui layout using frames and grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276663/tkinter-gui-layout-using-frames-and-grid/34277295#34277295)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add this statement `canvas1.create_window(250,250, window=w)` at the end of this code:

```py
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()

variable = StringVar(master)
variable.set("one") # default value

w = OptionMenu(master, variable, "one", "two", "three")
w.pack()
```

Comment: This doesn't quite solve the problem. Why are you trying to add the `OptionMenu` to a `Canvas` after it has already been added to a `Tk` window? This doesn't explain _how_ to change the `OptionMenu`'s position. See [answer] for more information on writing good answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can change position to anywhere to suit you by using `canvas1.create_window`.
In line 23, replace `pack()` with `canvas1.create_window`.

Try this:

```
import tkinter as tk


root=tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=300)
canvas1.pack()

username = tk.Entry(root)
canvas1.create_window(200, 140, window=username)
canvas1.create_text(100, 140, fill="darkblue", text="username")

password = tk.Entry(root)
canvas1.create_window(200, 180, window=password)
canvas1.create_text(100, 180, fill="darkblue", text="password")

variable = tk.StringVar(root)
variable.set("Facebook")

w = tk.OptionMenu(root, variable, "Facebook","Twitter","Spotify","Swiggy")
canvas1.create_window(150, 250, window=w)

button1= tk.Button(text='Go')
canvas1.create_window(250, 250, window=button1)

root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]