# How to fix to the left a button in tkinter with columnspan

Tags: python, tkinter

### Description

What I'm trying to do is an app with a navbar on top that depending on which one is shows different things on the body of the app (below the navbar). I'm using the grid so I'm iterating through a list and adding a button to the body of the app and they have columnspan but they position in the middle of the columnspan

[image]

This is how it looks right now.

### Desired Layout

[image]

This is a little sketch of the layout (the right bar below the navbar is a scrollbar which isn't implemented yet because I don't know yet how to do it)

### Code

```
import modules.configManager as configManager
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter.font as font
from os.path import dirname, abspath
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

imgDirectory = dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__))) + '\img'

logo = imgDirectory + '\logo2.jpg'


root = tk.Tk()


def linkMenu():
    links = configManager.readConfig()['linksList']
    i = 0
    for link in links:
        i = i+1
        linkB = tk.Button(root,text=link['link'],font=font.Font(font='Helvetica',size=8),width=30,relief='flat')
        linkB.grid(column=0,row=i,columnspan=4)

def navbar():

    buttonWidth = 18
    buttonHeight = 1
    myfont = font.Font(font='Helvetica',size=10,weight="bold")


    homeButton = tk.Button(root, text="Home",height=buttonHeight,width=buttonWidth,font=myfont)
    homeButton.grid(column=0,row=0)

    linkButton = tk.Button(root, text="Links",width=buttonWidth,font=myfont,command=linkMenu)
    linkButton.grid(column=1,row=0)

    groupsButton = tk.Button(root, text="Groups",width=buttonWidth,font=myfont)
    groupsButton.grid(column=2,row=0)

    resetButton = tk.Button(root, text="Reset",width=buttonWidth,font=myfont)
    resetButton.grid(column=3,row=0)

    exitButton = tk.Button(root,text="Exit",width=buttonWidth,font=myfont,command=exit)
    exitButton.grid(column=4,row=0)

def interface():
    navbar()

    root.title("LinkManager")
    root.geometry("1040x500")

    root.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance and if it isn't clear tell me please :D

Comment: Read about [notebook](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/complex.html#notebook) and [gui layout using frames and grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276663/tkinter-gui-layout-using-frames-and-grid/34277295#34277295), [Adding a scrollbar to a group of widgets in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3092341/7414759)

Comment: Oh thanks that would make it much easier thanks :D