# why can i place the location of this button

Tags: python, tkinter

the button wont go to postion i set it to when i run it could i get a little help please?

```
import tkinter
newbw=tkinter.Tk()  


def hub():    
    newbw.destroy()
    newbw=tkinter.Tk()
    newbw.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
    a=tkinter.Button(newbw, text="demonfight", command=dfpre)
    b=tkinter.Button(newbw, text="shop", command=shop)
    c=tkinter.Button(newbw, text="train", command=trainhub)
    d=tkinter.Button(newbw, text="quit", command=end)
    d.place(x=20, y=20)
    a.pack()
    b.pack()
    c.pack()
    d.pack()
```

Comment: You have called `d.place(...)` and `d.pack()`.  Which one do you want?

Comment: i want to place it

Comment: wait so the pack dosent have to be there when i do place() ?

Comment: The later `pack()` will override former `place()`.  So if you want `.place()`, remove `d.pack()`.

Comment: wait why is `d.place(x=20, y=20)` showing up on the left side i had it set to + + quadrent

Comment: @arandomdosfile Read [Why are multiple instances of Tk discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045401/why-are-multiple-instances-of-tk-discouraged) and [gui layout using frames and grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276663/tkinter-gui-layout-using-frames-and-grid/34277295#34277295)

Comment: @arandomdosfile Do you mean `+X+Y` inside `geometry(...)`?  But since you have called `newbw.attributes('-fullscreen', True)`, the `geometry(..)` will be overrided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three geometry managers: **pack**, **grid**, and **place**.  Using one of them is known as `mapping` a widget.

**Pack** and **grid** cannot be mixed. It's one or the other.
**Place** can be mixed with **pack** or **grid**, but it's really (in my opinion) the last choice because `placed` widgets are not detected by the outer frame when it autosizes.
So, because of the above, you were able to mix **pack** with **place** and not get an error.

Once you `map` something with a geometry manager, can you `unmap` and `remap` it. So, your first call to `d.place()` `places` the **d** widget. But then your second call to `d.pack()` overrides the `place()` and then `packs` the widget.

Because the default for `pack()` is side='top', you'll see your four widgets stacked, with  **a** on top, down to **d** on the bottom.

Also, your app doesn't work right because you create a function `hub()`, but you never call it.  Add:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    hub()
```

to the bottom of your program.

So, although your posted code is incomplete, try something more like this:

```
import tkinter

def hub():    
    newbw=tkinter.Tk()
    newbw.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
    a=tkinter.Button(newbw, text="demonfight", command=dfpre)
    b=tkinter.Button(newbw, text="shop", command=shop)
    c=tkinter.Button(newbw, text="train", command=trainhub)
    d=tkinter.Button(newbw, text="quit", command=end)
    #  d.place(x=20, y=20)
    a.pack()
    b.pack()
    c.pack()
    d.pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hub()
```