# splitting windows using frames in tkinter and python

Tags: python, tkinter, frames, tkinter-layout

I am trying to learn tkinter and how to organise a GUI using grids and frames. I have created to simple scrollbar list boxes but would like to place them both in one frame to the right side of the screen so the left hand side can be used for another frame. Could anybody help me with guidance of how to split the display into 2 frames please?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

my_window = Tk()
# frame_name = Frame(my_window)

my_list = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11',
           '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20']
my_list2 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11',
            '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20']


listbox_object = Listbox(my_window)
listbox_object2 = Listbox(my_window)
# listbox.pack()
listbox_object.grid(row=0, column=1)
listbox_object2.grid(row=0, column=3)

scrollbar_object = Scrollbar(my_window)
scrollbar_object2 = Scrollbar(my_window)
# scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
scrollbar_object.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='ns')
scrollbar_object2.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky='ns')

for item in my_list:
    listbox_object.insert(END, item)

for item in my_list2:
    listbox_object2.insert(END, item)

# attach listbox to scrollbar
listbox_object.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar_object.set)
listbox_object2.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar_object2.set)
scrollbar_object.config(command=listbox_object.yview)
scrollbar_object2.config(command=listbox_object2.yview)
mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tkinter gui layout using frames and grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276663/tkinter-gui-layout-using-frames-and-grid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not very clear what you want to do with the frame.
However, I can tell you that the elements in a GUI are hierarchical. So if you want to separate into two frames, you can do:

```
main_frame = Frame(my_window)
main_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nswe")

left_frame = Frame(main_frame)
left_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nswe")

# Button added just to see that there is a left frame, otherwise it will shrink
button_object = Button(left_frame, text="My Button")
button_object.grid(row=0, column=0)

right_frame = Frame(main_frame)
right_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nswe")

listbox_object = Listbox(right_frame)
listbox_object2 = Listbox(right_frame)
listbox_object.grid(row=0, column=0)
listbox_object2.grid(row=0, column=2)

scrollbar_object = Scrollbar(right_frame)
scrollbar_object2 = Scrollbar(right_frame)
scrollbar_object.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
scrollbar_object2.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky='ns')
```

Note that I added a global `main_frame` to encapsulate everything, as it is better practice than working directly with the Tk root.

Finally, if you want to design more closely your interface, you will need to use `columnconfigure` and `rowconfigure` to control how your interface split the unused space, e.g.

```
main_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=3)
main_frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
```

to tell your interface that 3/4 of the remaining horizontal space is attributed to left_frame (column 0 of main_frame) and 1/4 to right_frame (column 1 of main_frame)

Many things are not very intuitive in general with GUI design. In your case, I suggest to use the `bg` parameter while debugging:

```
main_frame = Frame(my_window, bg="BLUE")
left_frame = Frame(main_frame, bg="RED")
right_frame = Frame(main_frame, bg="GREEN")
```

so that you see clearly how your program split the space when you resize the window.

Comment: So main_frame contains left_frame and right_frame at row=0, column=0? and the col and row positions within the left and right frames are just in respect to themselves - I think that was the bit that was confusing me if ive understood correctly - thanks

Comment: Well `left_frame.grid(row=0, column=0,...)` means that left_frame is at row=0 and column=0 WITHIN ITS PARENT (main_frame). Similarly for `right_frame.grid(row=0, column=1,...)` which is at column=1. Oppositely, `main_frame.columnconfigure(0, ...)` applies to ALL ITS CHILDREN that are at column=0 (in this case, only left_frame).

Comment: It would be good to add missing lines of code from the question to make this solution runnable. Making this will motivate me to upvote (I was able to test it by merging with code from the original question).