# gui layout using grid in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

I have developed the following gui using grid in tkinter. I know there are other ways but grid is kind of more intuitive for me, consider I am a newbie with it. Here is the code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def make_form(row_c, col_c, list_names, type_input):
    #  variable definition
    col_range = 2
    value = []  # metti lunghezza list names!
    for ind, key in enumerate(list_names):
        row_c += ind
        lab = ttk.Label(root, text=key)
        lab.grid(column=col_c, row=row_c, sticky=tk.W, padx=5, pady=5)
        if type_input == 'in':
            value = ttk.Entry(root)
            value.grid(column=col_c + col_range, row=row_c, sticky=tk.E, padx=5, pady=5)
            value = value.get()
        elif type_input == 'out':
            value = ttk.Label(root, text='test_value')
            value.grid(column=col_c + col_range, row=row_c, sticky=tk.E, padx=5, pady=5)
        else:
            pass  # gestire eventuali messaggi di errore

    return row_c, col_c + col_range, value


def make_buttons(row_button, col_button, label):
    var_button = ttk.Button(root, text=label)
    var_button.grid(column=col_button, row=row_button, sticky=tk.W, padx=5, pady=5)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    # root.geometry("240x100")
    root.title('Titolo')
    root.resizable(1, 1)

    # configure the grid
    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    root.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
    root.columnconfigure(3, weight=1)

    #  gui template
    c_title = 0  # columnspan=4
    c_input_1 = 0  # columnspan=2
    c_input_2 = 3  # columnspan 2
    c_labels_1 = 2  #
    c_labels_2 = 4
    c_file_path = 0
    c_button_file = 4

    r = 0
    label = ttk.Label(root, text='Name window', borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
    label.grid(row=r, column=c_title, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.S, padx=5, pady=5)

    r = 1
    label = ttk.Label(root, text='Input 1', borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
    label.grid(row=r, column=c_input_1, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.S, padx=5, pady=5)
    label = ttk.Label(root, text='Input 2', borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
    label.grid(row=r, column=c_input_2, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.S, padx=5, pady=5)

    # input section
    r = 2
    list_labels = ['var_1', 'var_2', 'var_3', 'var_4', 'var_5']
    [row_1, col_1, values_1] = make_form(r, 0, list_labels, 'in')
    list_labels = ['var_1', 'var_2', 'var3', 'var_4', 'var_5', 'var_6', 'var_7']
    [row_2, col_2, values_2] = make_form(r, col_1 + 1, list_labels, 'in')

    #  input file section
    c = 0
    label = ttk.Label(root, text='Name window', borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
    label.grid(row=row_2 + 1, column=c, columnspan=3, sticky=tk.N, padx=5, pady=5)
    c = 4
    var = ttk.Entry(root)
    var.grid(row=row_2 + 2, column=4, columnspan=1, sticky=tk.W, padx=5, pady=5)
    var = var.get()

    B = tk.Button(root, text="Hello")
    B.grid(row=row_2 + 2, column=4, sticky=tk.E, padx=5, pady=5)

    r = row_2 + 3
    label = ttk.Label(root, text='output 1', borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
    label.grid(row=r, column=2, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.S, padx=5, pady=5)

    label = ttk.Label(root, text='output 2', borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
    label.grid(row=r, column=4, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.S, padx=5, pady=5)

    #  display output values
    # input section
    list_labels = ['var_1', 'var_2', 'var_3', 'var_4', 'var_5']
    [row_1, col_1, values_1] = make_form(r + 1, 0, list_labels, 'out')

    list_labels = ['var_1', 'var_2', 'var3', 'var_4', 'var_5', 'var_6', 'var_7']
    [row_2, col_2, values_2] = make_form(r + 1, col_1 + 1, list_labels, 'out')

    root.mainloop()
```

I found a valuable information here [tkinter gui layout using frames and grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276663/tkinter-gui-layout-using-frames-and-grid), but I am still struggling with my layout. I also have the following questions:
-why does the "Name window" not span through the whole gui? can i do it?

Comment: _"I would like to have some feedback about the code. "_ - this is not a proper type of question for StackOverflow. As for the other questions, please only focus on one problem at a time.

Comment: edited. now there is only one question

Comment: This code has two "name window" labels. Which one are you asking about?

Comment: both of them. It is the same label applyed to 2 frames

Answer (score 1):

> why does the "Name window" not span through the whole gui? can i do it?

Because you haven't told it to span the whole window. Your window has six columns but you've configured them to span either two or three columns.

If you want them to use the whole window in the x direction, you need them to span all columns. If you want the labels to stretch to fit, you will also need to use the proper `sticky` attributes.

```
label.grid(row=r, column=c_title, columnspan=6, sticky="ew", padx=5, pady=5)
...
label.grid(row=row_2 + 1, column=c_title, columnspan=6, sticky="ew", padx=5, pady=5)
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback. Where have I actually defined six column? :/ I thought I had defined four using root.columnconfigure()

Comment: @drSlump: somewhere in your code you're placing items in columns 4, 5, and 6.